# How to mongo-driver text seach

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver`

I want to search in mongo atlas by $search. I want to find a way to search text from all fields

```
func FindHuman(){
     clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(os.Getenv("DB"))
     client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

     if err != nil {
         return nil, err
     }

     db := client.Database("back_office").Collection("Human")

     search := bson.M{"$text": bson.M{"$search": "John"}}
     cur, err := db.Find(context.TODO(), search)


     var humans []humanStruck
     var human  humanStruck

     for cur.Next(context.Background()) {
          err = cur.Decode(&human)
          humans = append(humans, human)
     }

     fmt.Println(humans)
}
```

However I get the following error

```
(IndexNotFound) text index required for $text query
```

Comment: Do you have field with text index?

Comment: text index? have no

Comment: @Gibbs How to create text index ?

Comment: [MongoDB: Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)

Comment: @icza sorry I don't get. How whit Go?

Comment: @KrittametWongsakornpiriya You only need to create the index once, it doesn't matter if you create it using Go or with the mongo tools. It just has to exist, and then you can use `$text` queries.